# Invalid receiver type int

Tags: iphone, xcode, warnings, int

I cant seem to find what would be the problem here...

```
NSArray *oneMove;
oneMove = [[bestMoves objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
int from, to;
int temp = [[oneMove objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

from = [temp intValue]/100; //"Invalid receiver type int"
to = [temp intValue]%100;   //"Invalid receiver type int"

NSLog(@"%d, %d", from, to);
```

The thing is: it works and 'from' and 'to' get the right values but i get warnings at the indicated lines...

anyone knows why and how to fix that? (dont like them warnings when compiling ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

temp is already `int` value, no `NSNumber`. So you cannot send an `[temp intValue]` message to it.

Just use

```
from = temp / 100;
to = temp % 100;
```

**Edit:** Here is code that proves it works:

```
NSArray *bestMoves = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"499,340,124"]; // Example data
NSArray *oneMove  = [[bestMoves objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
int from, to;
int temp = [[oneMove objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

from = temp/100; // Code change
to = temp%100;   // Code change

NSLog(@"%d, %d", from, to);
```

Output is as expected 4, 99.

Comment: tried that but that doesn give me the right outcome. temp HAS to have only 4 digits like 3132 (which is what i get if i do it my way) but if i do what you suggested i get 97759792 instead...

Comment: I did not make any change to temp. Have you checked that oneMove does hold the value you expect? I guess it should be a NSNumber object. Then do NSLog("%d",temp); to see if this works. If it doesn't, your data model is broken.

Comment: the oneMove array contains 2 NSCFString objects... (as does the bestMoves Array) might that help in your analysis?

Comment: btw: this
int temp = [[[oneMove objectAtIndex:0] intValue] intValue];
gives me the same correct result... but still there is the invalid receiver thingy...

Comment: thx! your answer is certanly correct, but my problem started else where ;) the sting that gets seperated was composed in this way [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d", [possibleMoves objectAtIndex:i], wert]; when actually it should be like that: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d", [[possibleMoves objectAtIndex:i] intValue], wert];
thanks anyway! you helped me find the right tracks!

Comment: Did you actually do the code change? You cannot send intValue to an int. Please see my updated code.

Comment: yes! after i changed the way how i composed the string your code change worked fine. what im guessing is that at first i saved a pointer to the string instead of an int. so where i got the invalid receiver type warning its true that it would have sent the intValue message to an int but this int was at the same time a pointer and the compiler found the correct value for this... or something like that... anyway the problem originated a lot earlier in the code...